# What is the proper way of copying folders using Node.js

Tags: node.js, directory, filesystems, deep-copy

I'm making a program that involves copying files and folders using node.js. I know that to copy files, the correct way is to use `fs.copyFile` so that meta data is also copied. How do I copy folders/directories with node.js? Do folders have metadata, or can I just make a new folder with the same name as the source folder? Another question I have is it there is a method of copying files using `node.js` (I want to deep copy them, so I also want to copy the folders and files inside the folder).

Comment: you can use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to use any external packages. Is there a way of making it with just node.js?